# socat Virtual Serial Port on RPi3 data issue

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

I'm having issues trying to log and forward data to a program (opencpn). I've got NMEA data coming in from a serial device via a RS232>USB converter. This is fine. I was having issues with opencpn resetting the ttyUSB1 connection which terminated the logging to the txt file, so I added tee and used socat to forward the data on to a virtual serial port so that opencpn can't interfere with the logging.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 115200 raw
cat /dev/ttyUSB1 | formatdata | tee -a ~/LoggedData/formatteddata.txt &
sudo socat /dev/ttyUSB1,raw,echo=0 pty,link=/dev/ttyUSB13,mode=555,raw,echo=0,crnl &
```

I've got this to run on startup and after login when I 'cat /dev/ttyUSB13' I can see data, however it's a mess instead of a new NMEA sentence each line. If I enter the code into the terminal from scratch all is fine, NMEA sentences appear over ttyUSB13 just fine. The socat man page is a little confusing, can anyone put me in the right direction? Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks!